# Issues with permutation function and swapping string values

Tags: c++, permutation, eclipse-juno, arrays

Okay, so I need some help getting my string to swap around.

Here is the overall code of what I am trying to do, but I can't just move the string around. I started off trying to convert it to characters but the majority of replies said to just use the std::swap function, however I am really lost in using this...

My overall goal is to permute a string, which can be specified to a certain section of the string. I am new to C++, I am just unsure how to use C++ methods/functions in order to achieve this.

(there is also a main.cc and Permutation h. but its only for defining variables, skeletal code basically)

All help appreciated, I shall check back here in about 2 hours.

UPDATED CODE)

```
    #include <iostream>   // for cout
#include <cstdio>     // for printf()
#include <sstream>    // for stringstream
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Permutation.h"
using namespace std;

Permutation::Permutation() {
    /* nothing needed in the constructor */
}

void Permutation::permute(const string& str) {

    string stringnew = str;
    int j;
    int low = 0;
    int high = str.length();

    cout << stringnew << endl;

    for (j = 0; j <= high; j++) {
        string strtemp = stringnew[j];
        std::swap((strtemp + low), (strtemp + j));
        permute(str, low + 1, high);
        std::swap(str[j + low], str[j + j]);

    }
}

void Permutation::permute(const string& str, int low, int high) {
//  int j;
//  if (low == high) {
//      cout << str << endl;
//  } else {
//      for (j = low; j <= high; j++) {
//          std::swap(str[j + low], str[j + j]);
//          permute(str, low + 1, high);
//          std::swap(str[j + low], str[j + j]);
//      }
//  }
}
```

Comment: Prefer `std::swap` to making your own.

Comment: You don't need to convert a string to an array. In Java, this is needed because Java strings are immutable. But C++ std::string is mutable, so you can work on it directly, swapping its elements etc. Basically just replace all mentions of `a` in your code to `str`. Oh, and make the string non-const.

Comment: Can't you just use standard permutations with standard strings?

Comment: @PavelMinaev Can you give me more to go on...I'm slightly confused. If I make my a's into str's  then what about my swap function? Don't I need to use like substr or something? I literally know nothing of C++ so this is decently hard haha

Comment: @Austin You don't need to use `substr` - `std::string` supports indexing with square brackets, same as array, and you can use the result on the left side of the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must work through the class interface. You cannot get a writeable character array from a `std::string`.

What you *can* do is use the array subscript operator and access it as `str[i]`. You can also use iterators.

The reason for this is that prior to C++03, `std::string` was not required to be a character array. It could be discontinuous. At least one implementation used a `std::deque` style "array of pointers to arrays" backing store, which gave it fast insert, prepend and delete-from-the-middle abilities.

Also, from an Object Oriented programming design perspective, it is Not Nice to reach into an object's guts and rearrange them.

Just for fun because I wanted a break from work, some code that messes with a string using array subscripts:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void uc(std::string &s) 
{
    size_t i;
    const size_t len = s.length();
    for(i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }   
}

void mix(std::string &s) 
{
    size_t i;
    const size_t len = s.length();
    for(i=1; i<len/2+1; ++i) {
        std::swap(s[i-1], s[len-i]);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("Test String");
    uc(s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    mix(s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I changed my code around to this..
`void Permutation::permute(string& str, int low, int high) {
 int j;
 if (low == high) {
  cout << str << endl;
 } else {
  for (j = low; j <= high; j++) {
   std::swap(str[j + low], str[j + j]);
   permute(str, low + 1, high);
   std::swap(str[j + low], str[j + j]);
}}}`

However now my main is upset...
`p.permute ("Permute");
    p.permute ("--*--", 2, 4);` It says no matching function to call Permutation::permute(const char [6], int, int)

Comment: I was able to figure it out using this method. Thanks!


 `int low = 0;
 int high = str.length() - 1;
 // make sure the string is a permutation and not a partial mix.
 if (low == high) {
  cout << str << endl;
 } else {
  //Takes each initial letter, then permutes the remaining string. Then moves to next character.
  for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
   std::swap(str[low], str[i]);
   permute(str, low + 1, high);
   std::swap(str[low], str[i]);
  }

 }
 cout << endl << "--BREAK--" << endl << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Just take the c_str()-function

```
std::string str("I'm a text");
char *pStr = str.c_str();
```

Comment: `c_str` returns `const char *`.

Comment: sting::c_str() returns const char* not char*.

Answer (score 0):

This is C++ not java as in thread you pointed.
First of all

```
char[] x
```

is valid declaration only for compile time known sizes of table.

The other thing is that std::string does not have .toCharArray method but it has **.c_str()** method you can use to get **const char*** from std::string.

HTH